# java runtimeExceptio:java.lang.nullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am new to android and stuck in an exception of null Pointer.
I even Tried defensive coding but it's still showing error.

here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<SubjectType> subjects;
    private ArrayList<Days> days;
    private ExpandableListAdapter adapter;
    private ExpandableListView exv;
    private String DayNames[] = {"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"};
    private String TypeName[]=  {"Lecture","Practical","Tutorial"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        loadContent();

        exv = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView1);
        adapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(MainActivity.this, subjects);
        exv.setAdapter(adapter);
        collapseAll();


    }

    private void collapseAll() {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            exv.collapseGroup(i);
        }
    }

    private void loadContent() {

            int daySize,typeSize;
            Days day_1 = null;
            boolean False = false;
            SubjectType sub1=null;
            daySize = 5;
            typeSize = 3;

            for(int i=0;i<daySize;i++)
            {
                if(DayNames[i]!=null)
                {
                    Days day_12 = day_1;
                    day_12.setDayAttributes(DayNames[i], False);
                    days.add(day_1);
                }
            }

            for(int j=0;j<typeSize;j++)
            {
                SubjectType sub12 = sub1;
                sub12.setChecked(false);
                if(days!=null&&TypeName[j]!=null&&sub12!=null&&sub12!=null)
                {
                sub12.setDays(days);
                sub12.setSubjectTypeName(TypeName[j]);
                subjects.add(sub12);
                }
            }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and the log-cat display:

```
07-05 17:14:26.942: E/AndroidRuntime(991): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-05 17:14:26.942: E/AndroidRuntime(991): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{trying.expandables/trying.expandables.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 17:14:26.942: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
07-05 17:14:26.942: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
07-05 17:14:26.942: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
07-05 17:14:26.942: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
07-05 17:14:26.942: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-05 17:14:26.942: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-05 17:14:26.942: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-05 17:14:26.942: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 17:14:26.942: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-05 17:14:26.942: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-05 17:14:26.942: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-05 17:14:26.942: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-05 17:14:26.942: E/AndroidRuntime(991): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 17:14:26.942: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at trying.expandables.MainActivity.loadContent(MainActivity.java:54)
07-05 17:14:26.942: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at trying.expandables.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
07-05 17:14:26.942: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
07-05 17:14:26.942: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
07-05 17:14:26.942: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
07-05 17:14:26.942: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  ... 11 more
```

please help!

Comment: Which line is line 54 of MainActivity.java?

Comment: day_12.setDayAttributes(DayNames[i], False); is line 54

Answer (score 2):

The most interesting line of the stacktrace is

```
07-05 17:14:26.942: E/AndroidRuntime(991):  at trying.expandables.MainActivity.loadContent(MainActivity.java:54)
```

(quite often, the first line mentioning non-system code is the best place to start looking at)

According to my count, line 54 is

```
subjects.add(sub12);
```

and nowhere in your code I see subjects being initialized, which explains the NPE.

EDIT: although I was looking at the wrong line, the cause is the same, as already pointed out by TheCapn and Joachim Isaksson.  And I now see that you do

```
        SubjectType sub1=null;
        ...
            SubjectType sub12 = sub1;
            sub12.setChecked(false); // <--- same BOOM, other line.
```

Are we starting to see a pattern here?

Also, avoid dense stuff like

```
if(days!=null&&TypeName[j]!=null&&sub12!=null&&sub12!=null)
```

because

```
if( (days!=null) && (TypeName[j]!=null) && (sub12!=null) && (sub12!=null) )
```

is a whole lot easier on the eyes...

Comment: i initialized subjects, but same error and they are also initialized during loadContent()

Comment: I formatted OP code a little earlier so line numbers were not the same as in original code. Sorry, my bad. Now it is OP code.

Comment: @Pshemo np, fixed (and one more instance of the same problem identified)

Answer (score 2):

`onCreate` calls `loadContent` on line 3 of the routine.

Within the `loadContent` routine you call:

```
days.add(day_1);
```

In the first for loop. The declaration:

```
private ArrayList<Days> days;
```

...which is never instantiated. Put this somewhere before you try using it:

```
days = new ArrayList<Days>();
```

EDIT:

As others have said. Do the same for `subjects`

Answer (score 2):

Something's not quite right with your logic in `loadContent`;

```
Days day_1 = null;
```

...later, without another assignment to `day_1` followed by...

```
Days day_12 = day_1;                          // Sets day12 to null.
day_12.setDayAttributes(DayNames[i], False);  // boom
```

Answer (score -1):

The variable subjects doesn't have any values!